# Nautilus sidepanel disk drives

Tags: unity, nautilus, 16.10

I recently updated to Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak. I don't see disk drives in the left side panel of Nautilus any more.

I can access in the unity launcher, but I want them to be displayed and be accessible there in Nautilus

How can I fix it?

Comment: The new sidebar of Nautilus (3.20) introduces a longer path to accessing internal hard disk drives/partitions via "+Other Locations" although removable USB drives, etc. appear there as before.

Comment: If you have got a satisfactory answer, then please click the "tick", making it green, so that it gets marked as that.

Comment: The nautilus 3.20 disabled that feature :'(

Answer (score 0):

Press F9,
or select View > Show Sidebar in the Menu. Then click <kbd>+ Other Locations</kbd> you drives will show up along with any available network shares.

Right click on any of them and select "Add a bookmark" to make that one visible for a single click (14.04 and 16.04 at least).

Comment: the side bar is there , but the disks are not :(